# need to route postgres traffic on 5432 from local machine to remote machine running postgres on 5432

Tags: postgresql, ssh

I have 2 machines each running postgres on 5432. My requirement is I want to route postgres data on port 5432 from machine 1 to another machine running postgres on 5432. There should be no impact on application layer trying to connect to localhost:5432 on machine 1. I tried SSH tunneling but not sure on that. Any pointers?

Comment: What, both of them run postgresql locally?!  if so, then you cannot bind port 5432 any more except on a different interface..-.

Comment: both machines are running same application (so, have local postgresql running on 5432 and DB is exact same). My requirement is, application on machine 1, any traffic comming on 5432 locally, should be routed to machine 2 on port 5432.

Comment: Then you need to shut down the PG on the machine 1 and only *then* forward machine 2

Comment: Hi @AnttiHaapala, shutdown I can do, but how can I route the postgres traffic from machine 1 to machine 2?

Comment: It would work with `ssh -L localhost:5432:localhost:5432 machine2` on machine 1 *for as long as the connection is open*. Though it is somewhat questionable if `ssh` should be used - when the ssh connection crashes for one reason or another, then the tunnel is severed too...